# Automatically override return type of several functions in a child class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, inheritance, covariance, typescript-generics

I have a class that has several functions that return a new instance of itself and I want to extend the class and have those functions return an instance of the child class instead. e.g.

```
class A {
    constructor(public val) {

    }

    getAnother(val): A {
        return new A(val);
    }

    next(): A {
        return this.getAnother(this.val + 1);
    }

    double(): A {
        return this.getAnother(this.val * 2);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    getAnother(val): B {
        return new B(val);
    }

    next(): B {
        return <B>super.next();
    };

    double(): B {
        return <B>super.double();
    };

    getValAsStr() {
        return String(this.val);
    }
}

let b = new B(1);

console.log(b.next().getValAsStr()); // logs "2"
```

This does what I am trying to accomplish but ideally I wouldn't need to reimplement `next()` and `double()` in class `B` and manually cast the return type. I tried an approach using generics that lets me only override `getAnother()` in class B but it breaks the polymorphic relationship between A and B

```
abstract class I<TResult> {
    constructor(public val) {

    }

    abstract getAnother(val): TResult;

    next(): TResult {
        return this.getAnother(this.val + 1);
    }

    double(): TResult {
        return this.getAnother(this.val * 2);
    }
}

class A extends I<A> {
    getAnother(val): A {
        return new A(val);
    }
}

class B extends I<B> {
    getAnother(val): B {
        return new B(val);
    }

    getValAsStr() {
        return String(this.val);
    }
}
```

Is there an approach that is cleaner than my first approach and that maintains the relationship between A and B in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a polymorphic [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types).

```
class A {
    constructor(public val) {

    }

    getAnother(val): this {
        return new A(val);
    }

    next(): this {
        return this.getAnother(this.val + 1);
    }

    double(): this {
        return this.getAnother(this.val * 2);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    getAnother(val): this {
        return new B(val);
    }

    getValAsStr(): string {
        return String(this.val);
    }
}
```

(untested)

Comment: Ah yep that works. In my real world use case I'm trying to build a chain of processors. Each node in the chain takes a function that accepts the output from it's parent node and can return some new type. So essentially A is actually A<TIn, TOut> and `next<TNext>()` returns A<TOut, TNext>. So I don't think I can use polymorphic this as I need to specify different generics in the return type. But this answers the question I asked so I may post this as a separate question.